# Types of property 'id' are incompatible

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to return the information of a user I created by passing the attributes of the eb_user class in argument but I get an error.

This is the error I receive:

```
Argument of type '{ id: string; nom: string; prenom: string; mail: string; domaine: string; tel: string; color: string; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'eb_user'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

here is the users.component.ts file where I created the user

```
addUser() {
  const copiedData = this.data.slice();
  copiedData.push(this.createNewUser());
  this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
}
private createNewUser() {
  const nom =
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

  return {
    id: (this.data.length + 1).toString(),
    nom: nom,
    prenom: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    mail: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    domaine: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    tel: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
  };
}
```

eb_user.ts file:

```
import {EbRole} from './role';

export class eb_user {
    id: number;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    tel: string;
    mail: string;
    domaine: string;

    constructor(){
        this.id = null;
        this.nom = null;
        this.prenom = null;
        this.tel = null;
        this.mail = null;
        this.domaine= null;
    }

}
```

I expect the types of eb_users attributes to be returned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have strongly typed the `copiedData` as `eb_user[]`. Since you are returning the `id` as string from the `createNewUser()`, there is a mismatch in the types. You need to keep them same (either both be string  or both be number).

Answer (score 1):

Your id in the class it's a `number` meanwhile in your  `users.component.ts` you are returning a string by doing a `toString` ( `id: (this.data.length + 1).toString()` ).

Removing that toString() should work:

```
 return {
    id: (this.data.length + 1),
    nom: nom,
    prenom: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    mail: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    domaine: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    tel: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface EventCardProps
extends Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, 'id'> {
showBadge?: boolean;
size?: 'default' | 'small' | 'big';
name?: string;
location: string;
date: string;
image: string;
category?: string;
seats?: string;
className?: string;
```

}

Comment: It is not clear how your answer addresses the question.